# Typescript: how to get possible keys from const with limited values?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have the following code:

```
export const mapLayers: Record<string, SomeObject> = {
  layer_a: {},
  layer_b: {}
} as const;

export type LayerId = keyof typeof mapLayers;
```

`LayerId` will always be `string` and not `layer_a | layer_b` which I would expect.
It actually does work if I remove the `Record<string, SomeObject>` part. But then I lose the possiblity to limit what's in `mapLayers` values. How can I get proper inferred keys AND also the "limited" values?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGWQG8AoMgehoDpHKBfSyu5AN2gGdh0QyAIzIA7sDAALZGACeABxQx0ULnAA2AVxSjJwBNNEqA1j0oQAHvJWkEAnqUxx5AGTizeALmQAlYioATAB4HKFAAcwAaNCxcQmIwAD5kAF4KamR1d2gAfThvcmZIjKyPKBy8AtZmZDgeZDsQBwBuNktrKFI5RWQ3MoBJANTkYwhZdBgZBQgJ5CdXbKgeVo4yNfWAPQB%20NnYaLl5%20QQAmMQlJdE0u6bE9AzETM3abBvtHZz7eAHVzy7AAFRuaSoZFKuXyFCKJUWFSqLFq9UaLTaVhe3RQnygg1OaVG40m6Nm80xPB%20Uj%20gMUK3261p20oQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a case for the `satisifes` operator:

```
export const mapLayers = {
  layer_a: {},
  layer_b: {}
} satisfies Record<string, SomeObject>;
```

This tells typescript that it should infer the type strictly (similar to `as const`, without making properties `readonly`). In addition though, it tells typescript you want an error to happen if the result is incompatible with `Record<string, SomeObject>`

For more on `satisfies`, [see this documentation page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html)

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!
Only detail: optional properties in `SomeObject` will break, but this wasn't in the question. :)